# Sumatory of every link for a node? Bipartite

Tags: r, bipartite

I'm working on my Final's degree project about bipartite networks.

I have the next code in a bipartite weighted network:

```
prueba<-read.csv("matriz_prueba.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
head(prueba)

  PAIS_ORIGEN     AFG     ETH     TZA     PAK     VNM
1         USA 6686.77 1726.46  834.16 2044.88  192.19
2          EU  609.50  396.27  298.63  244.11   84.17
3         IDA  424.68 1637.79 1461.09 1150.64 1939.73
4         FRA   95.65   45.01   26.00   20.54  341.29
5         JPN  867.20  154.99  182.21  272.97 1622.79
6         DEU  754.42  164.52  207.36  233.14  194.22
```

I would like to know if there is any function in `bipartite` library that returns the sumatory of each edge for a node. For example:

(USA-AFG)+(USA-ETH)+...+(USA-VNM) => USA: 11.484,46

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**There is no reason to use the library specific function.**

You are reading an adjacency matrix in a form of a data frame. Use either `sum(prueba[1,])` or `sum(prueba[1,2:ncol(prueba)])`. The second case is if the first row of the data frame contains the names of the countries.

No need to use the library for this specific task.